# Azure Kubernetes .NET Core App to Azure SQL Database Intermittent Error 258

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, kubernetes, timeout

We are running a .NET Core 3.1 application in a Kubernetes cluster. The application connects to an Azure SQL Database using EF Core 3.1.7, with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 1.1.3.

At seemingly random times, we would receive the following error.

```
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Even though it seems random, it definitely happens more often under heavier loads. From my research, it appears as if this specific timeout is related to the connection timeout rather than the command timeout. I.e. the client is not able to establish a connection at all. This is not a query that is timing out.

Potential root causes we've eliminated:

- **Azure SQL Server Capacity:** The behaviour is observed whether we run on 4 or 16 vCPUs. Azure Support also confirmed that there are no issues in the logs. This includes the number of open connections, which is only around 50. We also ran load tests from other connections and the server held up fine.
- **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Versions:** We've been running on version 1.1.3 and this behaviour only started a week ago (2021-03-16).
- **Network Capacity:** We are maxing out at around 1-2MB/s at this stage, which is pretty pedestrian.
- **Kubernetes Scaling:** There is no correlation between the occurrence of the events and when we scale up more pods.
- **Connection String Issues:** Our system used to work fine, but regardless we changed a few settings mentioned in other articles to see if the issue would not resolve itself. Mars is disabled. We cannot disable connection pooling. We have `TrusServerCertificate` set to true. Here is the current connection string: `Server=tcp:***.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=60;TrustServerCertificate=True;`

**Update 1:**
As requested, an example of two timeouts that just occurred. It is a Sunday, so traffic is extremely low. Database utilization (CPU, Mem, IO) is sitting between 2-6%.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
```

We are also receiving errors on our database health checker when using this command: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.CanConnect()`

The above stack trace is the issue we are trying to solve versus this stack trace below of the SQL query timing out.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Comment: Maybe some transient errors.  Have you implemented any retry policies?

Comment: We tried enabling ```RetryOnFailure()``` in the EF Sql Server configuration. Did not make any difference unfrotunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270245/sql-server-dbcommand-timeout-with-net-core-container-under-load

Comment: I'd be hassling Azure support more about their Azure SQL DBs. SNI is the Server Name Indication portion of the TLS channel handshake and establishment that happens before the SQL login stage is reached. So it is getting a TCP connection to the server, starting TLS, but not finishing it to get to SQL login stage.

Comment: If you are not using private endpoints for SQL Azure, then the SQL connections must be going thru the AKS public LB. So, I'd suggest to check, just in case, the AKS public LB SNAT connections (you can check them from the Azure Portal (in the AKS infra resource group) > kubernetes LB > Metrics). More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard

Comment: We are using a private endpoint. Thanks @andresm53.

Comment: Are you using AKS? How did you configure your Azure SQL Server firewall and database firewall rules? When a pod is destroyed the IP changes. Are AKS and SQL in different vnets/subnets?

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu We have a private endpoint between the cluster and database. So it doesn't pass through any firewalls.

Comment: Hi @AndréHauptfleisch, did your problems get fixed? I still have a lot of similar problems - especially during high load. SQL database is running perfectly fine.

Comment: @DirkBoer: Yes, please see the accepted answer below. There was a global Azure network issue with DHCP. Saw your GitHub post too. You can DM me to see if I can help you out.

Comment: @AndréHauptfleisch we have been facing the exact described issue in our large cluster, running dotnet core services in AKS. There don't seem to be a pattern in versions of MS.Data.SqlClient, dotnet core runtime version, nor SQL database scaling. Thanks for the proposed answer - however, it would seem that syslog (or any other system logs) is not enabled on our nodes at all. Do you have a clue to why that is? Or where I can find the network logs?

Comment: @Hulvej: Which node images are you guys using? We're on "AKSUbuntu-1804containerd-2021.06.12". Should be pretty standard though. Are you sure you're logging into the correct node and not the POD? At any rate, as AlwaysLearning suggested, the best thing is to hammer Azure Support. If you have the "ReadSniError" in your stack trace, it is highly likely that it is an infrastructure, which they need to sort out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was an infrastructure issue at [Azure](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/issues/4341).

> There is a known issue within Azure Network where the dhcp lease is
> lost whenever a disk attach/detach happens on some VM fleets. There is
> a fix rolling out at the moment to regions. I'll check to see when
> Azure Status update will be published for this.

The problem disappeared, so it appears as if the fix has been rolled out globally.

For anyone else running into this issue in the future, you can identify it by establishing an [SSH connection into the node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) (not the pod). Do an `ls -al /var/log/` and identify all the `syslog` files and run the following grep on each file.

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep 'carrier'
```

If you have any `Lost carrier` and `Gained carrier` messages in the log, there is a some sort of a network issue. In our case it was the DHCP lease.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to bother with this @André Haupt, but would you lease provide me the instructions to add the installation of syslog to my docker file so I can see those logs?

Comment: @MatiasBello: These logs are on the host machine, and not inside the pod containers.

Comment: Wow ! really ? Thanks André! I'll look it up there then.

Comment: Ok, but I've tried following your instructions, and I see no "syslog" directory (Please see screenshot)
https://ibb.co/ggXymLZ

Comment: Which distro are you running? `lsb_release -a`

Comment: You mean on the pods? "buster-slim" (debian). Also tried "bionic" (ubuntu).

Comment: The Node image version is "AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2021.06.02"

Answer (score 4):

> from my research, it appears as if this specific timeout is related to the connection timeout rather than the command timeout

I don't think so.  The callstack goes through `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` so it's running a query, after a successful connection.

This is a CommandTimeout, caused by the client abandoning a long-running command.  The default CommandTimeout is 30sec.

To troubleshoot *why* the command is taking a long time, start with the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) and the related [Query Performance Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use).

There's some noise about this error on GitHub, but I don't see any evidence that there's anything other than ordinary Command Timeouts going on.  Eg if you run

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();

    var sql = @"waitfor delay '01:00:00'";
    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    //cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception  ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

You'll get (With Microsoft.Data.SqlClient):

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SqlClientTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\david\source\repos\SqlClientTest\SqlClientTest\Program.cs:line 34
```

Or slightly different for System.Data.SqlClient (which you appear to be using):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The difference between

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
```

and

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
```

is probably just the availability of the Win32Exception descriptions on Windows vs Linux.

Comment: The error code might be the same, but if you look at the stack traces, the point of failure differs. In prod, it often happens on the DbContext creation, which I believe only does a ```SELECT 1``` to see if the server is available. Afaik, the db server must be very busy before it will command timeout (currently at 3m) on that query. Also, the Azure db support checked and the server had sufficient resources.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace that shows that?  And a command can timeout without insufficient resources. For instance the long-running query could be caused by blocking.

Comment: Please see the updated post where I highlight the different stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using an Azure SQL Database without enough DTUs for the workload. The solution was to upgrade the database to a higher tier with more DTUs allocated.

[image]